# finding text in a string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find records where the post code starts with a certain set of characters from some 10,000 records, 1300 or so of which meet the select below.
My code is

Select * from table where mid(`postcode`,1,2 ) IN ("CV DE LE MK NN")

This returns a zero result
A typical postcode would be something like CV1 9AD

If I write

Select * from table where mid(`postcode`,1,2 ) = "CV"

I get the full list of records for post codes beginning with "CV"
I would have thought that the IN statement would work. Can anyone tell me why it does not?

Answer (score 3):

The `IN` operator expects a list of items, not a single string.
You need to structure your query as follows:

```
Select * from table where mid(postcode,1,2) IN ('CV','DE','LE','MK','NN');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the string comparison operators:

SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE postcode [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) 'CV%';

You can also make use of the powerful REGEXP operators:

SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE postcode [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) '[B-D][U-W]';
(will get the first letter from B to D  and second letter from U to W,
and so will pick up your desired postcodes - this was just a trivial
example for illustrative purposes.

Regular expressions can seem both forbidding and a pain to learn at first
(partially true!), but once mastered, quickly become indispensable.

Finally, take some time to peruse the [docco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) - there are lots of (sometimes
quirky) functions which can come in handy.

Comment: +1  for the `LIKE`. I have yet to find a need to use regexes.